# Load images dynamically without blocking UI in Javascript on mobile application?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, css, mobile

So I'm attempting to load images in javascript dynamically as the user is scrolling around. The entire application is offline and is written in HTML and javascript. The "scrolling" around behavior is done through CSS3 animations.

The problem is that when I set image.src = "foo.png" it blocks the UI until the image has loaded. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Does the document height grow as the **src** attribute is set? If so I would say that this is your problem, as the renderer has to calculate this before it gives scrolling control back to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How long is the UI being blocked? If it is local then I wouldn't have thought it much at all.

Anyhow, the reason the UI may be being blocked is because it needs to download the image to determine its **size**. If it doesn't know the image size it will not know how it will affect the layout.

The first think I would do is to set **with** and **height** attributes as soon as the tag is created.

Comment: Downloading the image is not the blocking factor. It downloads it fine using an Image object, but when setting the DOM element's src attribute in the onload callback causes it to block.

Comment: Firstly, is the HTML local, if so there is no reason to use the **onload event**, secondly the loading of the image no matter how quick will cause the renderer to re-calculate the styles - the question is does having the **width** and **height** attributes allow the renderer to skip this process? I am assuming that the document height is increasing as images are added so the renderer has to figure out how this changes the layout (ie you cant scroll until the document height is calculated).

Comment: Yeah after those changes it hiccups for only a couple ms while the image is loading but still is noticeable. Going to have to do something different.